# How to use dynamic nonce in ASP.NET MVC 4 for CSP

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, iis, content-security-policy, nonce

I have MVC application developed in ASP.NET MVC 4. I have using javascripts in several pages. Some of the javascripts are referenced as

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/bootstrap")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/js")
```

and also there are some inline scripts like

```
<script type="javascript">

   // javascript code
</script>
```

I want to implement Content Security Policy for this site. The site is hosted in IIS. So in IIS i add content-security-policy header in HTTP Response Header as

```
object-src 'none';
 script-src 'nonce-{random}' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' 'strict-dynamic' https: http:;
 base-uri 'self';
 report-uri https://csp.withgoogle.com/csp/<unique_id>/<application_version>
```

So every response will include this header.

Questions:

1. How do i add randomly generated nonce into script tags and importantly how IIS would know randomly generated nonce value so it can include in response header? (i am assuming every response will have unique nonce value)

Answer (score 3):

Using the OWIN middleware, you can inject the header pretty easily in ASP.NET MVC 5. Once you setup the OWIN startup (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-startup-class-detection) you can add this code to the startup to generate a dynamic CSP header:

#### EDITED

I updated the code below using `RandomNumberGenerator` instead of `RNGCryptoServiceProvider`, as the latter was marked obsolete by Microsoft:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.Use((context, next) =>
    {
        string nonce = null;
        using (var rng = RandomNumberGenerator.Create()) {
            var nonceBytes = new byte[32];
            rng.GetBytes(nonceBytes);
            nonce = Convert.ToBase64String(nonceBytes);
        }
        context.Set("ScriptNonce", nonce);
        context.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Security-Policy",
            new[] {string.Format("script-src 'self' 'nonce-{0}'", nonce)});
        return next();
    });
    //Other configuration...
}
```

Then you may add the following HTML helper to use it in your razor views:

```
public static class NonceHelper
{
    public static IHtmlString ScriptNonce(this HtmlHelper helper)
    {
        var owinContext = helper.ViewContext.HttpContext.GetOwinContext();
        return new HtmlString(owinContext.Get<string>("ScriptNonce"));
    }
}
```

Then you use this helper in your views:

```
<script type="text/javascript" nonce="@Html.ScriptNonce()">
    //my script body
</script>
```

The rendered result is something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" nonce="WpvQQK0FO/ZAljsQDGMLEgi2hrvIBVPQNak9zIWqRZE=">
    //my script body
</script>
```

Please, note that nonces don’t help you if the attacker can influence the body of a script element, where hashes can protect against that. However hashes have their own shortcomings, such as bloat in HTTP headers and being a little more fragile.

[Here the original reference link](https://vcsjones.dev/content-security-policy-nonces-in-asp-net-and-owin/).

Comment: instead of RNGCryptoServiceProvider we can use Guid.NewGuid()

Comment: Thanks @MichałRóżycki, it's better not use GUIDs. Despite they are quite random, they are not intended to be used as random numbers - their sole purpose is to uniquely identify entities, so they can be predictable.

Answer (score 2):

Inserting nonce tags and especially matching them up in CSP is often tricky. If your script code is static and does not include anything that changes it would be much easier to whitelist them based on their hash. If you remove 'unsafe-inline' many browsers will tell you which hashes need to be added.

And please note that your script-src including https: and http: will allow it to load ANY script on http and https. If your page is served over https active mixed content will not be allowed and scripts on http will not load as a result.

Comment: We have hundreds of inline scripts in our code. Is it the best practice that adding all their hash to webconfig?

Comment: I would strongly recommend to move them to one or more separate js files on the same server. Mainting the list of hashes will be a nightmare.

Comment: There are pros and cons in using hashes or nonces. This is an article that explains why to use nonces https://content-security-policy.com/nonce/